# How do I FTP-upload a Jekyll-made blog to look the same as on localhost?

Tags: jekyll

I have created a blog using Jekyll on WinXP and when I run `jekyll serve` the blog shows fine in a web browser when served on my localhost, `http://127.0.0.1:4000`. Rather than using GitHub, I am going to be publishing the blog on my own webserver. But when I FTP the `_site` folder there, it doesn't show properly. I'm getting a number of big grey rectangles and a huge Twitter icon, all almost as wide as the page itself. This is using the same web browser.

I thought the only thing I needed to upload was the `_site` folder. What could the problem be? Do I need to fiddle with `_config.yml`? I can't understand why the blog is showing fine locally but not on the webserver.

I have closely followed the instructions [here](http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com). For what it's worth, I specified Rouge rather than Pygments as the syntax highlighter, but I doubt that's the cause of the problem.

Comment: i think you need to upload what it is under _site folder but not the folder

Comment: @valentin - Thanks - this has fixed the problem! If you post that as an answer, I will accept it. Some sites say post "the _site folder", others say post "the contents of the _site folder". I'd assumed the first were right and the second were being over-flowery in their language, but I was wrong - the first were being vague and the second were taking care to be accurate. So thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect you need to upload what it is under `_site` folder but not the folder